# Spark LogicalPlan serialize/deserialize

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to save the DataFrame.queryExecution.optimizedPlan to some persistent and reuse it to create new DataSet in other spark application:
Using this API:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.ofRows(sparkSession, logicalPlan)
```

Can it be done? How?

Comment: I'm facing the same situation. Did you get the solution?

Comment: no, it seems to be impossible because it holds also the connection to the files or DB and it is not serialized...  :-(